# sass load mixin conditionally based on media query

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

Is it possibile to load/unload mixins based on a media query? Something like this:

```
@if @media (min-width: 768px) {
    @include mixin1;
}
@else {
    @include mixin2;
}
```

if the condition is met, `mixin2` should not be loaded at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, the sass compiles server side, not knowing the clients screen size. The compiled css will be used for all screen widths, thus:

```
@include mixin2;
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  @include mixin1;
}
```

Comment: yeah, my approach to the problem was completely wrong, ty.